# is the sentence "ce sont ses amies, elle leur montre les photos" correct?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels

from my textbook :  **"ce sont ses amies , elle (lui , leur , la) montre les photos"**

if i were to choose one , i would not choose any of them , actually i will go with something like **"se"** because **"Se montre"** is a reflexsive verb where **"se"** refers to **"ses amies"** so sentence should translate to : **"these are her friends, she shows them the photos"**

however my textbook says that the correct answer is **"leur"** which makes no sense to me because **"leur"** is a possessive adjective and should be used in something like : **"c'est leur maison"** (it's **their** house)

thanks in advance.

Comment: "Ces est ses amies" is blatantly wrong, it should be "ce sont ses amies". Are you sure this is what the textbook says ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Se" is indeed reflexive, but I think you may have the wrong idea of what a reflexive pronoun is: a reflexive pronoun is a pronoun that refers to the subject of the verb, and is used if the subject does an action to themselves.

Ex:

> Ils se lavent (they wash themselves)

Compare with the use of a personal pronoun:

> Ils les lavent (they wash them - not themselves)

In the sentence "elle (lui , leur , la) montre les photos", you should not select a relexive pronoun, as the subject is not showinng the pictures to herself. You need to select a personal pronoun that refers to a plural noun, and that has the function of indirect object. The only choice for that is indeed *leur*

> elle leur montre les photos

It has indeed the same form as the possessive adjective *leur*. Just note that the personal pronoun *leur* is always plural but never takes an "s" at the end, whereas the possessive adjctive is "leur" in the singular, and "leurs" in the plural.

> Il a vu leur maison (singular)
>
> Il a vu leurs maisons (plural)

Comment: i still have some confustion about reflexive verbs , for instance : "je t'aime" it translates to : "i love you" and not "i love yourself" despite that fact that the sensentce contains reflexsive pronoun "te" , another example would be "je t'invite" it translates to "i invite you" and not "i invite yourself" , why some reflexive verbs are not used in a reflexive way ?

Comment: @AmirWG > Once again the distinction between the subject (Je / I) and the complement (toi / t' / you) is important. As the action of the verb is towards the complement and not the subject "aimer" is not a reflexive verb in your example. "Je t'aime" = "Je aime toi".   "S'aimer" is a reflexive verb and could be used to describe the love between 2 people (or the self-love of someone on some occasions): "Ils s'aiment" => "They love each other". "Elle s'aime" => "She loves herself".

Comment: @AmirWG: I have also the feeling you are confused by French using sometimes the same form for both reflexive and personal pronouns (ex: "me"/"te" can be either reflexive or personal pronouns, whereas "se" is always reflexive, and "le/la/les/leur" pronouns are personal pronouns but never reflexive).  I suggest you check this out, it contains a great summary: https://www.dummies.com/languages/french/french-personal-pronouns/ (just note a typo for "elle" !)

Answer (score 2):

**"leur"** is a possessive adjective, but it is also an indirect object pronoun: it means **"them"**.

**"She shows them ..."** would translate to **"Elle leur montre ..."**

However, the first part the sentence ("ces est ses amies") is incorrect.